# Split effort across columns

Tags: split

I have this sheet where we have people allocated to project codes for particular time period (From and To dates). I want formula which can split the number of weekdays (excluding weekends) across columns labelled week-wise with dates starting on Wednesday's.

For eg.
If person A is allocated from 1-Jan to 30-Jan.
The effort split should appear as:

[image]

Comment: This looks like an excel sheet.. Perhaps tag it as well then.

Comment: sorry am new here.. how do i upload the file?